# MVVM light. A proper way to execute a method when property's value is really changed

Tags: wpf, properties, mvvm-light

This code allows to execute the method when the property is set.
It executes as much times as the property is set.
I would like to know a variant when the method executes only in case when the property's value is really changed.

```
public const string MyPropertyPropertyName = "MyProperty";

        private bool _myProperty = false;
      
        public bool MyProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return _myProperty;
            }
            set
            {
                Set(MyPropertyPropertyName, ref _myProperty, value);

                DoSomething();
            }
        }


        private void DoSomething()
        {

            // DO YOUR WORK

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Set` method should return a `bool` value that indicates whether the property was actually set then:

```
set
{
    if (Set(MyPropertyPropertyName, ref _myProperty, value))
        DoSomething();
}
```

If it doesn't return a value, you should either modify it or use your own custom `Set` method:

```
protected bool Set<T>(string propertyName, ref T storage, T value)
{
    if (Equals(storage, value))
        return false;

    storage = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly what you mean by "really changed", you can surround your call to `DoSomehting` like this :

```
if (value != _myProperty)
{
     DoSomething();
}
```

More information about the `value` keyword can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value)

Answer (score 0):

You could just compare the value to the backer prior to setting it.

```
        set
        {
            if(!Equals(value, _myProperty))
            {
                DoSomething();
            }
            Set(MyPropertyPropertyName, ref _myProperty, value);
        }
```

Perhaps passing in value to DoSomething if it needs the new value for the property.

The above code makes it clear what comparison is being done before running dosomething.
Unless you routinely call methods from every or most setters, I wouldn't be so keen on changing a standard method signature for an exceptional circumstance.

Comment: is it possible to execute method when the property has true? How this will look like?

Comment: Just substitute value == true in the if